# MacBook Pro goes black for a second or two and then comes back on

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro (mid 2012) 15″ goes black for a second or two while I'm using it and then comes back on as soon as I touch the trackpad, or sometimes it comes back on its own. It's very sporadic. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

That actually sounds like an intermittent connection caused by a broken wire/conductor, or a bad solder joint. Essentially, you have two ends of a conductor that *should* be joined, but mild vibration is causing them to make/break contact, causing the symptoms you describe.

However, you should confirm that your screen saver settings aren't set to turn on after a very short duration.

1. **System Preferences** >> **Desktop & Screen Saver** >> **Screen Saver** tab.
2. At the bottom-left, try setting **Start after** = Never

BTW, if you want easy method to manually enable the screen saver, click **Hot Corners** and set a corner for **Start Screen Saver**.

It would be good news if just the screen saver is causing the blank screen.

Otherwise, you should send the macbook in for repairs (when you have a break from needing it).